# How to parse single json object in android

Tags: android, json, android-studio, parsing

I am new to android and JSON.
I am trying to get JSON data (following one):

```
{ "user": [ { "id": "001", "name": "Raj Amal", "email": "raj.amalw@gmail.com" } ] }
```

And use its data in one of the android application text view .
So how can I deal to the above problem.

I have tried the below code but its giving exception.
Please help. Thanks

```
    {
    try{
            JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(jsonString);
            //Log.i(TAG,obj.getString(TAG_ID));
            String iid = obj.getString(TAG_ID);
            Log.i(TAG,iid);
            final TextView CardBalanceID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CardBalanceID);
            CardBalanceID.setText(iid);

       }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.i(TAG,"EXCEPTION");
        e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Comment: consider using `gson` library...what you have above might be ok for example you're showing but doesn't really scale as json gets more complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your id object is inside the `user` array. So you first need to parse that array. Please try the following code.

```
 try{
        JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(jsonString);
        JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray("user");
        String iid = jArray.getJSONObject(0).getString(TAG_ID);
        Log.i(TAG,iid);
        final TextView CardBalanceID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CardBalanceID);
        CardBalanceID.setText(iid);

    }catch(JSONException e){
        Log.i(TAG,"EXCEPTION");
        e.printStackTrace();}


}
```

Comment: Happy to help :) Here on SO we mark the answer as right which solves our problem.

Comment: I have marked it. Thanks for the information. Didnt know that (I am newbie to SO ).

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your code try this.

```
 {
        try{
                JSONObject obj=new JSONObject(jsonString);
                //Log.i(TAG,obj.getString(TAG_ID));
                JSONArray jsnArry = obj.getJSONArray("user");
                // if you have more than 1 object in Array 
                // then loop is needed otherwise you can use directly 0th item.
                for(int i=0;i<jsnArry.length();i++){ 
                    JSONObject jsnObj = jsnArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String iid = jsnObj .getString(TAG_ID);
                }

                Log.i(TAG,iid);
                final TextView CardBalanceID = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.CardBalanceID);
                CardBalanceID.setText(iid);

           }catch(JSONException e){
            Log.i(TAG,"EXCEPTION");
            e.printStackTrace();}
    }
```